# working with mat4 in the VertexShader

Tags: c, opengl, vertex-shader

Why does the first code work, but not the second?
The Code is in the Vertex-Shader.

First Code:

```
gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix * vec4(Position, 1.0);
```

Second Code:

```
mat4 View = mat4(
        ViewMatrix[0][0], ViewMatrix[1][0], ViewMatrix[2][0], ViewMatrix[3][0],
        ViewMatrix[0][1], ViewMatrix[1][1], ViewMatrix[2][1], ViewMatrix[3][1],
        ViewMatrix[0][2], ViewMatrix[1][2], ViewMatrix[2][2], ViewMatrix[3][2],
        ViewMatrix[0][3], ViewMatrix[1][3], ViewMatrix[2][3], ViewMatrix[3][3]
    );

gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * View * ModelMatrix * vec4(Position, 1.0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the GLSL spec about matrix constructors:

> Matrix components will be constructed and consumed in column major order.

The first 4 floats define the first colum of the new matrix, but you specify the first row of it. You are setting `View` to the *transposed* `ViewMatrix`.

Note that this absolutely mirros the C syntax and array conventions.

Comment: What derhass is trying to say is, that you're unintentionally transposing your matrix, hence things get messed up.

Comment: @datenwolf: Exactly. I actually had a sentence about transposing it in there, but somehow screwed it up before sending the answer. I edited it to make it more clear.